# Measuring force of a punch

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, acceleration, measurements, home-experiment

I'm trying to build a device that can measure the force of a punch. ​ My initial plan was to build a platform with 4 springs (one at each corner) and an accelerometer in the middle.

However, if the person doesn't punch in the middle, the value is going to be wrong. I have thought about adding a gyroscope and calculating the angulation, but then the algorithm is going to be way more complex.

I'm not really sure about this method, do you have a better way to measure the force of the punch that could be fixed on a wall?

Comment: Multiple accelerometers or you can measure the compression of the springs. Alternatively you could use a mechanical method that is less dependent on the force vector. How about leaf springs or a shock absorber?

Comment: @CuriousOne wouldn't a weighing machine be enough?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN: Sounds like a good idea. That's exactly the kind of mechanism that does this.

Comment: mesure -> measure ​ (I didn't spot that when I made my previous edit.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Why much around with accelerometers when the usual tools for this kind of thing are pressure transducers? Or are you trying to rig someway to use your phone as the data acquisition platform?

Comment: Ask them to punch 10 times and try hit the centre each time. Take the maximum force as the one that hit the centre.

Comment: Punching is abut accuracy as well as force. If someone can't hit the target, the punch is null anyway. It has the effect that it has.

Answer (score 0):

(1)
Measure out and draw a fine grid on the surface of an air hockey table.

(2) Set up a camera of known frame rate above the table facing down.

(3) Place a large, flat bottomed, relatively light object of known mass on the table, make sure it hovers freely.

(4) Punch the object horizontally, then analize footage to find impulse.

(Note) If you want to measure the approximate mass of your fist/forearm, dip it into water and measure the displacement. Humans have a density of about 1000kg m^-3, maybe a bit more because of arm bones.

Comment: Couple of comments here. First and foremost, the delivered impulse is certainly depends on the resistance of the target because the punch is not delivered as the free flight of an object and the kinetic chain is involved in any punch of consequence (indeed I would argue that any attempt to analyze punching in terms of physics 101 concepts is doomed to dismal failure). Secondly, the torque necessarily imparted to the object is almost certain to ground the opposing edge and render the measurement imprecise even for what it is. It's a reasonable starting notion, but the devil is in the details.

Comment: Punching a pendulum could actually be more accurate. Measuring the instantaneous force is generally very hard as it requires measuring acceleration over very short time scales.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Schematic]

The punch can be landed on the table and the ball is pushed through the liquid column and naturally the height the ball rises the force can be calibrated,

Now you want to build the machine that can be put to a wall. so you can make adjustments to the design or even get a different idea from this.

You drop a known weight at a measured height and calculate the force and you can calibrate the column accordingly it would be fairly accurate for your need.

You will definitely not get a state of the art machine with water but if you have some other fluids at your disposal the surely the accuracy will increase. the Less denser the fluid the more will be the accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the answers, I though I would have receive an email, but I didn't. So I moved on a little bit with the project and here is what I got now. [image]
I used these [springs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005S4JNBA), and I fixed an accelerometer in the middle of the wood plate. To determinate the force I was planning on using this formula: F = a(m + 2kt^2) where F is the force, a the acceleration in m/s^2, m the mass of the wood plate, k the spring constant and t the time between when the plate start to accelerate and when the acceleration has reached his maximum. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Here is some additional informations. 
I have ordered this accelerometer from Sparkfun: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9269, but I just realize that there is a maximum of 3G of acceleration. I also have these from China that are supposed to be able to go to 16G: http://www.ebay.com/itm/381374932942?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

Comment: Here is some pictures to help you ! https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ft5r27uogsca6ph/AAAzoDWD5pgdGFXR-4m2MMgRa?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You're measuring the wrong thing. Measure the *momentum* of a punch, not the "force". The force will be different if you hit something soft or hard, so you can't depend on that. The *momentum* is just the mass of hand+glove+forearm times *velocity* of punch. How to measure that? Hit the punching bag and see how far it swings.